# How to do fixed-point math instead of floating-point?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math, floating-point, fixed-point

I'm not the math uncle, but a real one told me this:

> "use fixed point instead of floating
>   point to do multiplication, division,
>   summation, trigonometry and
>   integration"

So instead of using double or float data types, what shall I do? Does anyone have a handy snippet or link that shows the difference for non-math-uncles?

Comment: Most fixed-point libraries don't do trig or calculus.

Comment: What's your reason for fixed-point calculation? Do you hope to make your application faster?

Comment: I think your question here is valid, but not very well worded...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the below for link for fixed point, I'm sure will be useful for you ...

http://cnx.org/content/m11054/latest/

http://www.digitalsignallabs.com/fp.pdf

Comment: Here is one more http://www.seattlerobotics.org/encoder/200008/fixedpoint.html  Fixed vs Float http://www.dspguide.com/ch28/4.htm

Answer (score 2):

The language itself does not support anything except integers and floating-point values. However, you can easily simulate fix-point values by integers. If you, for example, decide that you want a fix-point value with three decimals, you can use, for example 12345 to represent 12.345. Addition is straight forward, and you can surely work out how to express the other basic operations.

However, there is no support for doing trigonometry etc.

Answer (score -1):

Whoever the "math uncle" is, he's wrong.

Unless you really understand what you're doing, whatever fixed-point implementation you come up with will *not* be more accurate from using native double-precision and the system math library.  If you did really understand what you were doing, you wouldn't be asking the question.

So don't worry about it.  Use `double`.  If you run into precision problems, first **understand them**, and only worry about how to avoid them after you understand.

Comment: Given you don't know the domain of his problem space and the sizes of the numbers involved, it seems like you should not be able to make a definitive statement about whether or not he needs fixed-point objects or not.

Comment: Agree with aperkins. It is possible to achieve higher precision with a 64-bit integer than double if we allocate more bits to the decimal part.

Comment: @user172818: of course it's possible.  However, "floating-point" need not mean "double".  Most commodity hardware has support for 80-bit floating point (with 64 bits of accuracy with correct rounding, which integer hardware does not have).  There are good arbitrary-precision floating-point libraries, which can deliver results as accurate as desired.  I'm not saying there is no place for fixed-point -- I'm saying that naive use of fixed point has the potential to introduce subtle bugs, so you shouldn't use it just because a "math uncle" said to.